# openxml writing to excel template not interrating thru cells correctly

Tags: c#, excel, openxml-sdk

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, true))
{
    WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart;
    SharedStringTablePart sstpart = workbookPart.GetPartsOfType().First();         
    SharedStringTable sst = sstpart.SharedStringTable;
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First(); 
    Worksheet sheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
    var cells = sheet.Descendants();
    var myrows = sheet.Descendants();

    string[] columns = new string[] { "POC Sworn Document Reviewer Name", "# of POC Sworn Docs Reviewed", "Total # of Hours Spent on Total POC Sworn Docs Reviewed for the Month", "Commentary", "Submitter Name on behalf of Firm", "Submitter Email address on behalf of Firm" };
    int totalrowcount = dt.Rows.Count;

    int NFirstRowNum = 5;
    int NlastRowNum = totalrowcount + 5;
    int NRowCount = 0;

    foreach (Row newrow in sheet.Descendants<Row>().Where(r => r.RowIndex.Value >= NFirstRowNum && r.RowIndex.Value <= NlastRowNum))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("newrow " + newrow.ToString());
        uint newIndex = (newrow.RowIndex + 1);
        string curRowIndex = newrow.RowIndex.ToString();
        string newRowIndex = newIndex.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("curRowIndex " + curRowIndex.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("newRowIndex " + newRowIndex.ToString());

        foreach (DataRow dsrow in dt.Rows)
        {
            object col1 = dsrow[0].ToString();
            object col2 = dsrow[1].ToString();
            object col3 = dsrow[2].ToString();
            object col4 = dsrow[3].ToString();
            object col5 = dsrow[4].ToString();
            object col6 = dsrow[5].ToString();

            foreach (Cell dtc in newrow)
            {
                string s = dtc.CellReference.ToString();
                //strip the nubmer from A4,B4,C4 etc
                string result = Regex.Replace(s, "[^a-zA-Z]", "");
                switch (result) //based on your columns
                {
                    case "A":
                        dtc.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);
                        dtc.CellValue = new CellValue(col1.ToString());
                        break;
                    case "B":
                        dtc.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);
                        dtc.CellValue = new CellValue(col2.ToString());
                        break;
                    case "C":
                        dtc.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);
                        dtc.CellValue = new CellValue(col3.ToString()); //   
                        break;
                    case "D":
                        dtc.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);
                        dtc.CellValue = new CellValue(col4.ToString()); //
                        break;
                    case "E":
                        dtc.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);
                        dtc.CellValue = new CellValue(col5.ToString());
                        break;
                    case "F":
                        dtc.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);
                        dtc.CellValue = new CellValue(col6.ToString());
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                } // switch        
            } //  foreach (DataRow dsrow in dt.Rows)
        }//  foreach (cell dtc in newrow)    
    } //  foreach (Row newrow 
    spreadSheet.SaveAs("c:\\Monthly\\POC.xlsx");
    spreadSheet.Close();
} //using
```

Comment: Please explain the issue in more detail, what the problem is, and what you expect to happen instead.

Comment: so the data table gets repeated the same row on the excel spreadsheet vs putting in all the rows..

Comment: I was able to run your code, but I don't know what your Excel spreadsheet or your DataTable look like, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Jim Krgstrom 3 1 N/A Michelle dr@gmail.com
Jodie Tsher 4 1.33 N/A Michelle dr@gmail.com
Joel Giens 2 0.67 N/A Michelle dr@gmail.com
Kate Laesky 1 0.33 N/A Michelle dr@gmail.com
Michael Cord 6 2 N/A Michelle dr@gmail.com

Comment: it has multiple rows but the first row is repeated..